# Continue session even i close the browser

Tags: php, session

I use session for login/logout purpose. when user get log-in the user_id is store it in session variable. The user is already log-in and when i close the browser and restart it the session is expire and user also get automatically logout.

My query is how user continue his log-in even he close his browser without using cookie.

Comment: `without using cookie` is not a good constraint for this case

Comment: use `cookies`  too. and cross check every time

Comment: 2 thinks: Sessions also uses cookies, and the whole point of a session, is that it ends when the session is over (including when the browser closes).

Comment: can you just explain how to use session cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: what are the parameter i need to pass. where should i use this function. i have started the session on login page as well as on logout page.

Comment: `session_set_cookie_params()` can be used to set the lifetime span of the session cookie. The session will still expire when you close the browser.